# Insert and Select at the same time in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
create procedure Insert_Maintenance
(
@PlateNo nvarchar(10),
@MaintenanceType nvarchar(150),
@Name nvarchar(300),
@MaintenanceDate date,
@Qty int,
@IndivisualVal float,
@TotalVal float,
@Notes nvarchar(300)
)
as
insert into Maintenance(MaintenanceNo, PlateNo, MaintenanceType, AutoCenterNo,MaintenanceDate, Qty, IndivisualVal, TotalVal, Notes)
values ((1+(select Max(MaintenanceNo) from Maintenance)), @PlateNo, @MaintenanceType, (select AutoCenterNo from AutoCenter where Name = @Name), @MaintenanceDate, @Qty, @IndivisualVal, @TotalVal, @Notes)
Select Max(MaintenanceNo) AS MNo from Maintenance
```

A user will insert new maintenance operation via VB.NET interface. The information of the maintenance will be inserted into the database. The ID of the maintenance will increase by 1; as it is shown in the code. Since this is the case, after inserting the information I want to show a message that tells the user that information entered correctly and the ID of this operation is the value of `MNo`.

Basically, the problem is not with the VB.NET code because the message works fine but the problem is related to the select statement that shows the maintenance ID to the user.

The code in VB.NET

```
Dim ConnectString As String
        ConnectString = ""
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectString)

        'Dim parm1 As SqlParameter
        'parm1 = New SqlParameter("@MaintenanceNo", SqlDbType.Int)
        'parm1.Value = MaintenanceNoTextBox.Text

        Dim parm2 As SqlParameter
        parm2 = New SqlParameter("@PlateNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        parm2.Value = PlateNoComboBox.Text

        Dim parm3 As SqlParameter
        parm3 = New SqlParameter("@MaintenanceType", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        parm3.Value = MaintenanceTypeTextBox.Text

        Dim parm4 As SqlParameter
        parm4 = New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        parm4.Value = NameComboBox.Text

        Dim parm5 As SqlParameter
        parm5 = New SqlParameter("@MaintenanceDate", SqlDbType.Date)
        parm5.Value = MaintenanceDateDateTimePicker.Value

        Dim parm6 As SqlParameter
        parm6 = New SqlParameter("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int)
        parm6.Value = QtyTextBox.Text

        Dim parm7 As SqlParameter
        parm7 = New SqlParameter("@IndivisualVal", SqlDbType.Float)
        parm7.Value = IndivisualValTextBox.Text

        Dim parm8 As SqlParameter
        parm8 = New SqlParameter("@TotalVal", SqlDbType.Float)
        parm8.Value = TotalValTextBox.Text

        Dim parm9 As SqlParameter
        parm9 = New SqlParameter("@Notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        parm9.Value = NotesTextBox.Text

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = connection
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert_Maintenance"
        'cmd.Parameters.Add(parm1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm3)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm4)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm5)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm6)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm7)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm8)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm9)

        Try
            connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dreader As SqlDataReader
            dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim a As String
            a = dreader("MNo").ToString
            MessageBox.Show("Information entered, ID is " + a)
            dreader.Close()
            'MaintenanceNoTextBox.Text = ""
            PlateNoComboBox.Text = ""
            MaintenanceTypeTextBox.Text = ""
            NameComboBox.Text = ""
            'MaintenanceDateDateTimePicker.Value = ""
            QtyTextBox.Text = ""
            IndivisualValTextBox.Text = ""
            TotalValTextBox.Text = ""
            NotesTextBox.Text = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Something wrong  (" + ex.Message + ")")
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
```

Any suggestions guys !! Thanks

Comment: What is the code that you have used? Also why didn't you use an Identity field for MaintenanceNo ?

Comment: Please - **do not** do a `MAX(column)+1` to increase your ID's - this **WILL** fail at some point when your system is busy! Let SQL Server handle this on its own, using an `INT IDENTITY` - only that is safe under load.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to just change one line and remove a bunch of unnecessary code

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand() 
cmd.Connection = connection cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
cmd.CommandText = "Insert_Maintenance" 
.... you need to build the parameters collection here .....
Try 
     connection.Open() 
     Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar() ' <- Instead of ExecuteNonQuery '
     if result IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("The Mno is:" & Convert.ToInt32(result)
     End If
```

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns the first column of the first row in your results. This should resolve the VB.NET side of your code. Of course, if you don't need to control the values inserted in the column MaintenanceNo then the next action to take is to set the Identity property to Yes in the field properties. In this way you could remove the last lines of your storedprocedure and forget to pass anything for the MaintenaceNo field

```
 INSERT INTO Maintenance(PlateNo, MaintenanceType, AutoCenterNo,MaintenanceDate, Qty, 
                         IndivisualVal, TotalVal, Notes)
           VALUES (@PlateNo, @MaintenanceType, 
                   (select AutoCenterNo from AutoCenter where Name = @Name), 
                   @MaintenanceDate, @Qty, @IndivisualVal, @TotalVal, @Notes)

 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `ID` of `Maintainance` table should be auto-increment. For achieving that you can set `Is Identity` to `Yes`

In the end of insert if you want the ID than you can get by

```
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

If you want to increment `ID` manually then try this :

```
declare @newid int
Select  @newid = Max(ISNULL(MaintenanceNo, 0)) from Maintenance 
set @newid = @newid + 1
```

then use `@newid` for insert and in the end `Select @newid`